# socket call recvfrom appears to be stuck in infinite loop

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I've inherited a piece of code from one of my colleagues that I need to tidy up and turn into some in-house IP.

My problem is reading the socket. I have debugged the code and I can see that the socket is opened correctly. Everything runs fine until the interpreter runs the following line of code

```
    data, addr = any_struct.recv_socket.recvfrom(2048)
```

The interpreter goes nuts and I have to kill python through the task manager to stop it. I've tried using a debugger to step through the code, but it can't/won't step into the recvform call.

I'm in the early stages of turning this code into something worthwhile. Any suggestions as to how I can debug/fix this problem? I'm sure I'm going to kick myself when I find out what the problem is, but no lightbulbs at the moment.

I have used sockets before, but that was quite some time ago in C, not even C++

Comment: There's not a lot of info to go on here, so you'll not get a lot of suggestions either. Start by adding print to see what's going on, and check that recvfrom() actually succeeds.. There's no need to step into recvfrom though - it works. Also what does "go nuts" mean ? Is it just blocking ? Perhaps noone is sending you any data.

Comment: I can't add print. I can trace the code and see that it gets to recvfrom, but after that the interpreter takes off. I've no idea what it's doing - no time outs for sure. I've tried stepping, but again, the debugger freezes and the interpreter take off as soon as I hit recvfrom. What's here is as much information as I have on the problem. I've not seen anything similar described in the search I ran before posting. Every line of code until this line appears to be running as intended. The socket instance appears to be correct, after that I've no idea what or where to start looking.

Comment: Well, your program will sit in recvfrom until the end of time, unless it receives any data. Are you sure someone is sending data to your soucket ?

Comment: How do you deduce 'stuck in an infinite loop' from 'interpreter goes nuts'? What is the actual evidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nos has already mentioned in the comments, if there is no data to receive then the call would generally block until there was data to return. However, your application sitting there waiting for input doesn't meet any sensible definition of the interpreter "going nuts" so I'll assume this isn't the case.

Three possibilities spring to mind. One is that the socket is set to non-blocking when it's created - check the socket options that are used. In this case, of course the function won't block - in Python I believe this is communicated via an appropriate error.

The second possibility is that the socket is connection-oriented (e.g. TCP) and the connection has been closed - this would result in any `recv()`-family call returning empty data as soon as you call it, which typically leads to busy loops if the code hasn't been written with this in mind.

The third possibility is that some other part of your application (perhaps even another thread of execution?) has closed the socket under your feet and you're calling `recvfrom()` on an invalid socket. I would rather expect this to raise an immediate exception.

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Confirm the exact type of socket in use - if connection-oriented (e.g. TCP) then I suggest just using `recv()` instead of `recvfrom()`.
2. Put some trace indicating the return code of `recvfrom()`. If you can't print to standard output then open a file with append mode and write to that. If you have literally no means to get debug trace into your code then debugging any problem is going to be like ice-skating uphill I really suggest you address that. Try looking at the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module for a convenient way to do this (but for now just dumping in a hard-coded filename might be easier).
3. Make sure you wrap the `recvfrom()` call in a generic `try...except` which catches all subclasses of `Exception` and logs some trace. You can always re-raise them if you want to do this without affecting the flow of the code.

Based on the results of the above, you can choose your next steps. If the interpreter is "going nuts" when `recvfrom()` hasn't returned, then this means either you've hit some odd bug in Python or the libraries it's using (unusual!); or you've got other threads in your application which are causing the issue.

One final thought is that if you're on Windows then I'm not sure whether the firewall might lead to odd behaviour in `recvfrom()` if your application isn't enabled; but I would still expect this to manifest itself as either an odd return code or exception from `recvfrom()` within Python.

Comment: Other aspects of work conspired to keep me away from this for a bit. In our application using a socket is not the best approach, so we've changed our tack to use PCAP. Works for me.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for accepting anyway. One point on PCAP is you're aware it has the potential to miss packets if for some reason your user-space application can't keep up with the packet rate? If that's a problem you may need to hook in at a lower level (e.g. netfilter within the kernel if you're using Linux).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. We use PCAP a lot in our CPP code, just not so much in python, we've got used to it's nuances in that environment.